# Definitive tabletop segmentation?

Tags: ros, kinect, pcl, tabletop-object-detector, ecto

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After a day of searching I have frustratingly been bounced to all realms of segmentation from ecto, to writing my own pcl implementation, to deprecated tod packages.  All I want to do is fast and simple tabletop object segmentation with a kinect in ROS Electric.  Can anyone point me to a *working* and documented implementation of this?

Thanks!!!

-KM

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33221/definitive-tabletop-segmentation?/) by [kmaroney](https://answers.ros.org/users/735/kmaroney/) on ROS Answers with karma: 204 on 2012-05-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way is to use [tabletop_object_detector](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tabletop_object_detector).
I had used it on my own platform and its working perfect! It's a tutorial which is contains some hints for using tabletop_object_detector:

[Writing a Simple Pick and Place Application](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Simple%20Pick%20and%20Place%20Application)

By the way this Package is also have capability of recognizing objects by its 3d model database! but for segmentation the only work that you need to do is to call it's  object_segmentation service which is returns the position of segmented objects!

Good Luck!

---

Originally posted by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) with karma: 717 on 2012-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kmaroney](https://answers.ros.org/users/735/kmaroney/) on 2012-05-03**:
Thanks for the answer Alireza!  The tabletop_object_detector has not been updated since last May according to the logs.  It will not compile out of the box (affected from the transition between geometric_shapes_msgs and arm_navigation_msgs).

**Comment by [kmaroney](https://answers.ros.org/users/735/kmaroney/) on 2012-05-03**:
Fortunately, I got it to compile and test successfully!  If anyone is interested please feel free to email me and I would be happy to provide a working and tested copy against ROS Electric.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-10-28**:
Wow! Is there any progress or resources to learn? Thank you~